# List c# distinct by item and sum other items

Tags: c#, linq, list

Imagine a list of objects:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Total {get; set;}
}
```

And now, my list contains 3 objects:

```
new Foo {Name="object", Total=3};
new Foo {Name="object", Total=7};
new Foo {Name="object", Total=5};
```

How to distinct by the name and sum the totals? i.e. The List will have just one object:

```
new Foo {Name="object", Total=15};
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Object` is definitely not a good name for a custom class...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use grouping.

```
var groupedList = (from ol in objectList

                    group ol by ol.Name
                        into grp
                        select new foo
                        {
                            Name = grp.Key,
                            Total= grp.Sum(ex => ex.Total),
                            City = grp.Select(ex => ex.City).FirstOrDefault(),
                            Country = grp.Select(ex => ex.Country ).FirstOrDefault(),
                            Phone = grp.Select(ex => ex.Phone).FirstOrDefault()
                        }
    ).ToList();
```

Comment: And if I want that the "groupedList" returns me a List<Foo>()?
select new Foo{
           Name = grp.Key,
           Total= grp.Sum(ex => ex.Total)
      } 
Right? (I added the object after the New)... Imagine now, that in object Foo i have a lot of variables... Name, Total, city, address, country, ...

Comment: You would just put `foo` after the `new`.  I've updated my answer to reflect it.  This assumes the the properties `Name` and `Total` exist in the `foo` class.

Comment: You are not understand my doubt, but I will try to explain you. I have a List<Foo> with 100 items. Considers that the Foo has Name, Total, City, Country, Phone as variables... 4 regists (of Foo) has the same Name. I want to "merge" them. How? To Sum the total between them. So, I want the final List<Foo> with 97 items. Did you understand? Thanks very much for you attention.

Comment: Do the 4 with the same name, also have the same city, country, and phone?

Comment: How do you plan to merge the city, county, and phone then?

Comment: I updated my answer to show you how to get the first city, country, and phone.  But if they are all different, then there needs to be some logic to merge the values.

Comment: Oh, in that case, my updated answer should work just fine for you.  When you group, the group is kind of a mini list that you can query and get more values.  So, you can use lambda expressions inside of your linq query.

Comment: No problem,  If this answer helped you, please marked it as the answer to help others find it easier. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this:

```
var newTotalList = yourList.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(x => new
        {
            Name = x.Key,
            Total = x.Sum(y => y.Total)
        })
    .ToList();
```

What this code does is, simply, first group the elements by name, and then sum the Total fields of all the elements inside the group.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<Object> list = ... // make a list somehow
var totalsPerName = list
    .GroupBy(o => o.Name)
    .Select(group => new Object { Name = group.Key, Total = group.Sum(o => o.Total) })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group by `Name`  and then just sum up by `Total`:

```
var l = new List<Object>
{
    new Object {Name="object", Total=3},
    new Object {Name="object", Total=7},
    new Object {Name="object", Total=5}
};

var result = l.GroupBy(o => o.Name)
              .Select (grp => new Object 
                            { 
                                Name = grp.Key, 
                                Total = grp.Sum(o => o.Total)
                            });
```

`result` is now:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Group your elements by Name, and then for each group, select a new object whose name is name value grouped by for this group, and Total is the sum of all Totals in the group:

```
var groupdObject =list
    .GroupBy(o =>o.Name)
    .Select(g => 
       new 
       {
         Name = g.Key, 
         Total = g.Sum(o=>o.Total)
       });
```